# How to compute a limit: $\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{(-a+bi)x}$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

This might probably be a very simple limit to compute, but I can't really figure it out.

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{(-a+bi)x}$$

I'm told a is positive. I'm pretty sure it should be 0, but I'm not sure how to get there. Tried to rewrite it as a fraction, tried using Euler's formula, but I'm definitely going wrong somewhere. The imaginary part is basically the one I'm not sure how to handle.

Apologies if this is really trivial. Any hints/tips are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} |e^{-(a+bi)x}|=\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-ax}=0$$

Comment: though only if $a>0$

Comment: @OlivierMoschetta Which is stated in the question

Comment: Oh yes of course (I didn't downvote you in case you're wondering)

Comment: Well, that was unexpectedly simple. Thank you!